# Suggestion of a book for basic algebra?

Tags: book-recommendation

In my country (United Mexican States) it's very famous the book called "Algebra" from Aurelio Baldor to basic math. But i'm curious, what do they use in your countries? Do you know any famouse book for this?

Answer (score 1):

According to me it has to be Algebra for dummies and to be fair you should really stick to the coaching material your coaching institute is providing you if any. The best suggestion anyone can give you about the best books will still be your seniors so feel free to ask them.Theyll be the ones who can answer your questions the best!

Ps-- I'm from India
Please upvote if you liked the answer

Comment: Well heh, I passed these courses very long time ago, I'm just wondering because now im teching those courses, In my experience there is always better things and ideas I havn't heard of. To enclose myself to A.Baldor isn't wise from my point of view.